# React-Native: Firebase Error: No Firebase App [DEFAULT] has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error when I was trying to connect firebase with my React Native App.

Firebase Error: No Firebase App [DEFAULT] has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)

I have added my code here-

```
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
    import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

   // Your web app's Firebase configuration
const RNfirebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "........",
  authDomain: "note-app-rn.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "note-app-rn",
  storageBucket: "note-app-rn.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: ".....",
  appId: "......"
};

const app = initializeApp(RNfirebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this,

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const RNfirebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "........",
  authDomain: "note-app-rn.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "note-app-rn",
  storageBucket: "note-app-rn.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: ".....",
  appId: "......"
};

let app;
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    app = firebase.initializeApp(RNfirebaseConfig )
} else {
    app = firebase.app()
}

const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Shivam, 

I tried this but this problem happen- 

`Unable to resolve module @react-native-firebase/auth from D:\App-Development\firebase-auth\App.js: @react-native-firebase/auth could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules`

``

Comment: install @react-native-firebase/auth `npm i @react-native-firebase/auth`  , @react-native-firebase/firestore `npm i @react-native-firebase/firestore` and @react-native-firebase/app `npm i @react-native-firebase/app`

Comment: Do you need to have the firebase sdk at all when using react-native-firebase?

Comment: does this code go in index.js?

Answer (score 4):

Did it happen during migration to new `React Native` architecture?

Remember to change your import:

- from: `@import Firebase;` in `AppDelegate.m`
- to: `#import <Firebase.h>` in `AppDelegate.mm`

Comment: source for this??

Comment: my debugging, won't be able to find the link where it was explained

Comment: Its already as is and does not work

Comment: Do not forget to add `[FIRApp configure];` in the `AppDelegate.mm` also, everything is explained here https://rnfirebase.io/#configure-firebase-with-ios-credentials

Answer (score 1):

The main source of the error is related to initialize config setting.

Checkout this usage;

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "............",
    authDomain: "............",
    projectId: "............",
    storageBucket: "............",
    messagingSenderId: "............",
    appId: "............",
    measurementId: "............"
}

if (!firebase.apps.length){
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

Comment: https://rnfirebase.io/#configure-firebase-with-ios-credentials follow this guide